# iPlanet removing HTTP header information

Tags: http-headers, iplanet

I want to remove these two details from HTTP response headers. I am using iPlanet Web Server. I could not find a way to do that in configuration file. Any suggestion on how to remove these info in iPlanet?

```
Server: “Microsoft-IIS/7.5”, “nginx/1.0.11” 
X-Powered-By:
```

Comment: Ok, I figured it out:

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out:

1. for Server version, go to server.xml and add this tag 
   `<http><server-header></server-header> </http>`and set it to none.
2. for x-powered-by, I was using weblogic so I modified config.xml and there is tag element named `<x-powered-by-header>NONE</x-powered-by-header>`. set it to none and you're done! :)